# React Component Typescript: Error while unit testing react typescript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write unit test code of a react component written in typescript. I am getting the below issue. When I am trying to test using jest and enzyme. Can anyone. Please, help in writing it as I am new to testing.

> Argument of type 'LoginComponent' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'ReactElement
>   ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)>'.

Did lot of search. But was not able to find the proper solution. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is `LoginComponent` a child of `React.Component`?

Comment: ** class LoginComponent extends React.Component **

Comment: Can you post the code for the test and the component code as well (simplified)

Comment: I got the issue. I was writing the code in the .ts file. I changed the extension to .tsx. It is working fine now. 

Now I am looking for how to test React hooks in unit testing